# How to use pretrained models in tensorflow estimator api?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

There are many pretrained models available online, how to include those model in the tensorflow estimator api with other layers? I want to specifically use the estimator api as it distributes the the execution of the graph in different devices automatically. How to include the pretrained model for end to end training ?